# Classifier scores normalized for comparison, using log scale

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, logarithm

What's a good method to compare the scored results of different classifiers?

For example, let's say I have a classifier that deals with 12 different classes of fruit. 
Out of these 12 classes, 4 of them represent different views of an apple, 4 represent views of a banana, and 4 represent a pineapple. This is a multi-class classifier, and given an image, it assigns a score to all of the possible 12 fruit classes that the image might belong to. The class that got the highest score is selected as THE class of the image.

Now in addition to that - I have 3 individual classifiers, one for apples, one for bananas, and one for pineapples. Each classifier deals with 4 different views of an individual fruit.

I want to compare whether using the single 12-class classifier gives better results than using a combination of the individual 4-class classifiers.

When I run the 12-class classifier on images of apples, the results are indeed less accurate than the results of running the individual apple classifier, and the same goes for bananas and pineapples.

What I want to do now is build a combination of the 3 classifiers. So my program will run all 3 classifiers on a single image and tell me what the most likely class is.

The problem is - how can I normalize the scores across the different classifiers, so that I can make a comparison among the the 3 classifiers' classes and choose the class with the highest score? Although the method used to train the individual classifiers was the same, I doubt I can directly compare their scores without some kind of normalization.

Would it be practical to simply convert all the scores to the log scale and then compare them?

Comment: If I understand correctly - you're saying that running a classifier with 12 possible classes gives less accuracy than running the specific 4-class classifier (but that's because you are assuming that you have certain information when you run only a single fruit 4-class classifier no?)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. But the situation is: I have one set of training data, for 12 classes. I use all of it to train the 12-class classifier. Then I divide that data into 3 chunks, one per fruit, and use each chunk to train an individual fruit classifier. Now I have one set of testing data. I run the 12-class classifier on it & get some results. Then I split the test data into 3 chunks (one per fruit). And run each of the individual classifiers on a chunk. When I run the apple classifier on apple images, I do get higher accuracy. (But haven't tried on non-apple images yet).

Comment: I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to compare

Comment: I'm not sure how you split your data to train individual classifiers? In this case you should you should use one against rest method - say in your training apple classifier your target should be 1 for apples and 0 for _all_ the rest

Comment: To simplify it into really small numbers, it was like... images 1 to 4 show apples, 5 to 8 show bananas, and 9 to 12 show pineapples. And then images 13 to 20 show negatives. So the apple classifier was actually trained on *five* classes, images 1 to 4 representing 4 classes for each view of an apple, and images 13 to 20 to classify a negative class. The banana classifier was trained on images 5 to 8 to recognize 4 classes of bananas,& on the same set of negatives (images 13 to 20) as the apples. Same with the pineapple classifier...was that a bad idea? So they're actually 5-class classifiers

Answer (score 1):

A popular method to normalize classifiers is done by Platt-Scaling, which is implemented in libSVM. Its a straight forward normalization as described in the following link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling